# How do I set encryption settings per Devise Class?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi StackOverflow community, I'm trying to solve an issue whereby I am wrapping Devise around a legacy model in a Ruby on Rails 3.2 application.

In this app, I actually have 2 pre-existing devise models: Representative and Admin.  These two classes use all standard devise configuration and use default password encryption.  I need to wrap Devise around a third model, Dealer, which already has a pre-existing, custom SHA1 password encryption implementation.  I'd like to leave this encryption implementation in place while I work on adding Devise to this model and not force me to reset several hundred users passwords.  Is it possible to set the password encryptor to SHA1 for just this one model, leaving the other two aforementioned classes alone?

I'm still combing the documentation looking for a way to pass options to the devise-encryptable plugin, but so far have yet to find what I'm looking for.  Hopefully the community can help me with my search.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out.

1) Added `gem 'devise-encryptable'` to Gemfile

2) Added :encryptor => :legacy_sha1 options hash to model.

```
class DeviseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :encryptable, :encryptor => :legacy_sha1
end
```

3) Added a custom Encryptor class to lib/devise/encryptable/encryptors/legacy_sha1.rb

```
module Devise
  module Encryptable
    module Encryptors
      class LegacySha1 < Base
        def self.digest(password, stretches, salt, pepper)
          string = #secret routine!
          Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Works perfectly.